# Why does my query for interval differences return one result to few?

Tags: mysql, query, aggregate, interval

I'm trying to query a MySQL database with hourly timeseries data but I'm stuck with (daily) aggregation.

My raw data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM emoncms.custom_registers 
    -> WHERE timestamp >= '2016-08-24' AND timestamp < '2016-08-25';


+-----+------+---------------------+----------------+
| id  | node | timestamp           | register_value |
+-----+------+---------------------+----------------+
| 299 |   10 | 2016-08-24 00:00:03 |        869.458 |
| 300 |   10 | 2016-08-24 01:00:00 |        869.825 |
| 301 |   10 | 2016-08-24 02:00:03 |        870.202 |
| 302 |   10 | 2016-08-24 03:00:01 |        870.616 |
| 303 |   10 | 2016-08-24 04:00:05 |        870.977 |
| 304 |   10 | 2016-08-24 05:00:03 |        871.376 |
| 305 |   10 | 2016-08-24 06:00:01 |        871.759 |
| 306 |   10 | 2016-08-24 07:00:00 |        872.156 |
| 307 |   10 | 2016-08-24 08:00:04 |        872.629 |
| 308 |   10 | 2016-08-24 09:00:02 |        873.038 |
| 309 |   10 | 2016-08-24 10:00:01 |        873.512 |
| 310 |   10 | 2016-08-24 11:00:01 |        874.009 |
| 311 |   10 | 2016-08-24 12:00:01 |        874.429 |
| 312 |   10 | 2016-08-24 13:00:00 |        874.894 |
| 313 |   10 | 2016-08-24 14:00:04 |        875.331 |
| 314 |   10 | 2016-08-24 15:00:04 |        876.715 |
| 315 |   10 | 2016-08-24 16:00:04 |        877.249 |
| 316 |   10 | 2016-08-24 17:00:04 |        878.672 |
| 317 |   10 | 2016-08-24 18:00:04 |         879.19 |
| 318 |   10 | 2016-08-24 19:00:04 |        879.603 |
| 319 |   10 | 2016-08-24 20:00:04 |        880.027 |
| 320 |   10 | 2016-08-24 21:00:04 |        880.386 |
| 321 |   10 | 2016-08-24 22:00:05 |        880.787 |
| 322 |   10 | 2016-08-24 23:00:00 |        881.218 |
+-----+------+---------------------+----------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When querying for interval differences:

```
mysql> SELECT t2.node, 
    -> ROUND(MIN(t2.register_value - t1.register_value),3) AS register_diff, 
    -> t1.timestamp AS start_interval, t2.timestamp AS stop_interval 
    -> FROM custom_registers AS t1 INNER JOIN custom_registers AS t2 
    -> on t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp WHERE t1.node = t2.node  
    -> AND t1.timestamp >= '2016-08-24 00:00:00'  
    -> AND t1.timestamp < '2016-08-25 00:00:00'  
    -> GROUP BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.timestamp;

+------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| node | register_diff | start_interval      | stop_interval       |
+------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   10 |         0.367 | 2016-08-24 00:00:03 | 2016-08-24 01:00:00 |
|   10 |         0.377 | 2016-08-24 01:00:00 | 2016-08-24 02:00:03 |
|   10 |         0.414 | 2016-08-24 02:00:03 | 2016-08-24 03:00:01 |
|   10 |         0.361 | 2016-08-24 03:00:01 | 2016-08-24 04:00:05 |
|   10 |         0.399 | 2016-08-24 04:00:05 | 2016-08-24 05:00:03 |
|   10 |         0.383 | 2016-08-24 05:00:03 | 2016-08-24 06:00:01 |
|   10 |         0.397 | 2016-08-24 06:00:01 | 2016-08-24 07:00:00 |
|   10 |         0.473 | 2016-08-24 07:00:00 | 2016-08-24 08:00:04 |
|   10 |         0.409 | 2016-08-24 08:00:04 | 2016-08-24 09:00:02 |
|   10 |         0.474 | 2016-08-24 09:00:02 | 2016-08-24 10:00:01 |
|   10 |         0.497 | 2016-08-24 10:00:01 | 2016-08-24 11:00:01 |
|   10 |         0.420 | 2016-08-24 11:00:01 | 2016-08-24 12:00:01 |
|   10 |         0.465 | 2016-08-24 12:00:01 | 2016-08-24 13:00:00 |
|   10 |         0.437 | 2016-08-24 13:00:00 | 2016-08-24 14:00:04 |
|   10 |         1.384 | 2016-08-24 14:00:04 | 2016-08-24 15:00:04 |
|   10 |         0.534 | 2016-08-24 15:00:04 | 2016-08-24 16:00:04 |
|   10 |         1.423 | 2016-08-24 16:00:04 | 2016-08-24 17:00:04 |
|   10 |         0.518 | 2016-08-24 17:00:04 | 2016-08-24 18:00:04 |
|   10 |         0.413 | 2016-08-24 18:00:04 | 2016-08-24 19:00:04 |
|   10 |         0.424 | 2016-08-24 19:00:04 | 2016-08-24 20:00:04 |
|   10 |         0.359 | 2016-08-24 20:00:04 | 2016-08-24 21:00:04 |
|   10 |         0.401 | 2016-08-24 21:00:04 | 2016-08-24 22:00:05 |
|   10 |         0.431 | 2016-08-24 22:00:05 | 2016-08-24 23:00:00 |
|   10 |         0.371 | 2016-08-24 23:00:00 | 2016-08-25 00:00:01 |
+------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which totals to 12.131. Unfortunately, my query for aggregation only sums 23 intervals, instead of 24. It misses the 0.371 value. What's wrong with my query?

```
    mysql> SELECT t1.timestamp AS stop_interval, t2.register_min,  
        -> t2.register_max, (register_max - register_min) AS register_diff   
        -> FROM emoncms.custom_registers AS t1,   
        -> (SELECT timestamp, ROUND(MIN(register_value),3) AS register_min,   
        -> ROUND(MAX(register_value),3) AS register_max   
        -> FROM emoncms.custom_registers WHERE timestamp >= '2016-08-24'   
        -> AND timestamp <= ('2016-08-25'+ INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)   
        -> GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), WEEK(timestamp), DAY(timestamp)  
        -> ) AS t2 WHERE t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp;

+---------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| stop_interval       | register_min | register_max | register_diff |
+---------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| 2016-08-24 00:00:03 |      869.458 |      881.218 |        11.760 |
| 2016-08-25 00:00:01 |      881.589 |      881.589 |         0.000 |
+---------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why are you grouping by t1.id?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of these?

```
SELECT * FROM emoncms.custom_registers 
    WHERE timestamp >= '2016-08-24'
      AND timestamp  < '2016-08-24' + INTERVAL 25 HOUR;

SELECT * FROM emoncms.custom_registers 
    WHERE timestamp >= '2016-08-24'
    ORDER BY timestamp
    LIMIT 25;
```

Note the use of 25, not 24.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid sql, it appears to work in MySQL (unless you add ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to @@sql_mode), but may produce in-deterministic results. If I understand your intention you want to get current and previous row per node. From what I understand window functions are soon to make it into MySQL, but are not yet there. It's a breeze using either LEAD or LAG to solve your problem, but you probably cant use these:

```
select node, timestamp ts1
    , lead(register_value) over (partition by node order by timestamp) - register_value as diff 
    , lead(t1.timestamp) over (partition by node order by timestamp) ts2 
from custom_registers
```

Without window functions first step is to find current and next row:

```
select t1.node, t1.timestamp ts1, min(t2.timestamp) ts2 
from custom_registers t1 
left join custom_registers t2 
    on t1.node = t2.node 
   and t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp group by t1.node, t1.timestamp;

+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| node | ts1                 | ts2                 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   10 | 2016-08-24 00:00:03 | 2016-08-24 01:00:00 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 01:00:00 | 2016-08-24 02:00:03 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 02:00:03 | 2016-08-24 03:00:01 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 03:00:01 | 2016-08-24 04:00:05 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 04:00:05 | 2016-08-24 05:00:03 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 05:00:03 | 2016-08-24 06:00:01 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 06:00:01 | 2016-08-24 07:00:00 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 07:00:00 | 2016-08-24 08:00:04 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 08:00:04 | 2016-08-24 09:00:02 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 09:00:02 | 2016-08-24 10:00:01 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 10:00:01 | 2016-08-24 11:00:01 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 11:00:01 | 2016-08-24 12:00:01 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 12:00:01 | 2016-08-24 13:00:00 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 13:00:00 | 2016-08-24 14:00:04 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 14:00:04 | 2016-08-24 15:00:04 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 15:00:04 | 2016-08-24 16:00:04 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 16:00:04 | 2016-08-24 17:00:04 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 17:00:04 | 2016-08-24 18:00:04 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 18:00:04 | 2016-08-24 19:00:04 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 19:00:04 | 2016-08-24 20:00:04 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 20:00:04 | 2016-08-24 21:00:04 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 21:00:04 | 2016-08-24 22:00:05 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 22:00:05 | 2016-08-24 23:00:00 |
|   10 | 2016-08-24 23:00:00 | NULL                |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

24 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Note the null on the last row, it means there is no next row.

Now we can use this derived table and join it with the original table twice:

```
select x.node, abs(t3.register_value - t4.register_value) as diff
     , x.ts1, x.ts2 
from (
    select t1.node, t1.timestamp ts1, min(t2.timestamp) ts2 
    from custom_registers t1 
    left join custom_registers t2 
        on t1.node = t2.node 
       and t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp 
    group by t1.node, t1.timestamp
) as x 
join custom_registers t3 
    on x.node = t3.node and x.ts1 = t3.timestamp 
join custom_registers t4 
    on x.node = t4.node and x.ts2 = t4.timestamp 
order by x.node, x.ts1;
```

This will produce 23 rows using you sample data, I'm not sure what you want to do with the last row since there is no next row there.

```
+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| node | diff  | ts1                 | ts2                 |
+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   10 | 0.367 | 2016-08-24 00:00:03 | 2016-08-24 01:00:00 |
|   10 | 0.377 | 2016-08-24 01:00:00 | 2016-08-24 02:00:03 |
|   10 | 0.414 | 2016-08-24 02:00:03 | 2016-08-24 03:00:01 |
|   10 | 0.361 | 2016-08-24 03:00:01 | 2016-08-24 04:00:05 |
|   10 | 0.399 | 2016-08-24 04:00:05 | 2016-08-24 05:00:03 |
|   10 | 0.383 | 2016-08-24 05:00:03 | 2016-08-24 06:00:01 |
|   10 | 0.397 | 2016-08-24 06:00:01 | 2016-08-24 07:00:00 |
|   10 | 0.473 | 2016-08-24 07:00:00 | 2016-08-24 08:00:04 |
|   10 | 0.409 | 2016-08-24 08:00:04 | 2016-08-24 09:00:02 |
|   10 | 0.474 | 2016-08-24 09:00:02 | 2016-08-24 10:00:01 |
|   10 | 0.497 | 2016-08-24 10:00:01 | 2016-08-24 11:00:01 |
|   10 | 0.420 | 2016-08-24 11:00:01 | 2016-08-24 12:00:01 |
|   10 | 0.465 | 2016-08-24 12:00:01 | 2016-08-24 13:00:00 |
|   10 | 0.437 | 2016-08-24 13:00:00 | 2016-08-24 14:00:04 |
|   10 | 1.384 | 2016-08-24 14:00:04 | 2016-08-24 15:00:04 |
|   10 | 0.534 | 2016-08-24 15:00:04 | 2016-08-24 16:00:04 |
|   10 | 1.423 | 2016-08-24 16:00:04 | 2016-08-24 17:00:04 |
|   10 | 0.518 | 2016-08-24 17:00:04 | 2016-08-24 18:00:04 |
|   10 | 0.413 | 2016-08-24 18:00:04 | 2016-08-24 19:00:04 |
|   10 | 0.424 | 2016-08-24 19:00:04 | 2016-08-24 20:00:04 |
|   10 | 0.359 | 2016-08-24 20:00:04 | 2016-08-24 21:00:04 |
|   10 | 0.401 | 2016-08-24 21:00:04 | 2016-08-24 22:00:05 |
|   10 | 0.431 | 2016-08-24 22:00:05 | 2016-08-24 23:00:00 |
+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
23 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If all you are interested in is date total, something like:

```
select node, dt, min_val, max_val, max_val-min_val as diff 
from (
    select node, date(timestamp) dt, min(register_value) as min_val, max(register_value) as max_val 
    from custom_registers 
    group by node, date(timestamp)
) as t;
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
| node | dt         | min_val | max_val | diff   |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
|   10 | 2016-08-24 | 869.458 | 881.218 | 11.760 |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

EDIT: I noticed now that there actually is a value for next day in your sample. Adding that:

```
insert into custom_registers values (323,10,'2016-08-25 00:00:01',881.588);

select x.node, abs(t3.register_value - t4.register_value) as diff, x.ts1, x.ts2 
from (select t1.node, t1.timestamp ts1, min(t2.timestamp) ts2 
      from custom_registers t1 
      left join custom_registers t2 
          on t1.node = t2.node 
         and t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp 
      group by t1.node, t1.timestamp
) as x 
join custom_registers t3 
    on x.node = t3.node 
   and x.ts1 = t3.timestamp 
join custom_registers t4 
    on x.node = t4.node 
   and x.ts2 = t4.timestamp 
where ts1 >= '2016-08-24 00:00:00' 
  and ts1 < '2016-08-25 00:00:00' 
order by x.node, x.ts1;

[...]

|   10 | 0.370 | 2016-08-24 23:00:00 | 2016-08-25 00:00:01 |
24 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Day aggregation becomes:

```
select node, dt, min_val, max_val, max_val-min_val as diff 
from (select node, date(timestamp) dt, min(register_value) as min_val
           , max(register_value)  as max_val 
      from custom_registers 
      group by node, date(timestamp)
) as t;
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
| node | dt         | min_val | max_val | diff   |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
|   10 | 2016-08-24 | 869.458 | 881.218 | 11.760 |
|   10 | 2016-08-25 | 881.588 | 881.588 | 0.000  |
+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.71 sec)
```